# String variable in wpdb query does not work

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I can't get results from such query:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$result = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM hp_tempusers WHERE email = %", $email);
```

It's always empty.
But if I make:

```
$email = 'email@email.com';
```

everything will work.
I can't find the mistake and I will be very pleasant for any help.

Comment: thanks! but it still returns null. it's not the first time I face this problem.

Comment: try this `$result = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM hp_tempusers WHERE email = '$email', ARRAY_A);`

Comment: with last expression it works. thanks a lot guys!

Comment: ah... no, does not work

Comment: $wpdb->prepare()
this is the answer

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution. This code works:

$result = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM hp_users WHERE user_email = %s", $my_email));

Other ways do not work with dynamic string variables

Comment: it does not matter what table and column. it did not work. and it could not work. i tried many tables and methods until understood how to do it. so i don't understand your irritation. if you don't want to waist time just relax

Answer (score 0):

Use placeholder [`%s` for string](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Placeholders) instead of `%` with [`$wpdb->prepare`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) method.

```
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$result = $wpdb->get_row(
    $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM hp_tempusers WHERE email = %s", $email)
);
```

---

Or simply use the variable within the string.

```
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$result = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM hp_tempusers WHERE email = '{$email}'");
```

Comment: thanks! but it's just mistake in my question. the problem is, this code $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM hp_tempusers WHERE email = %s", $email); returns null

Comment: @www :  try `$result = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM hp_tempusers WHERE email ={$email}");`

Comment: the same. Null. i think, something wrong with the string. because if i send 1 and select id, it works

Comment: the answer is to use $wpdb->prepare() in this case, otherwise it will not work